# Criterion for $x^n=2 \mod p$ to have a solution

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any criterion to check whether the equation

\begin{equation}
x^n=2 \mod p
\end{equation}
has an integral solution for a general integer $n \geq 3$?

Comment: You'd need to find the order of $2$. If you have that information, what would the conclusion (for integer solutions) be?

Comment: Use Fermat's little theorem, $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ for all non-zero $x$. If you can find a $k$ such that $kn-1$ is a multiple of $p-1$. then $x \equiv x^{kn} \equiv 2^k \pmod p$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, that would solve the problem. But is there a criterion to find the order of 2 modulo a general prime number other than a explicit computation?

Comment: @Wenzhe Then you should provide that context in the question itself. IE State that you know how to use the order of 2, and are wondering if 1/ There is an approach that doesn't use it, or 2/ How can we find it without tons of computation.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see. I guess for a very general prime number, there is no explicit and efficient formula to compute the order of a very general integer mod $p$. Certainly more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e$ be the order of 2 (i.e. the smallest power such that $2^e \equiv 1 \mod p$) and let $f = (p-1) / e$. Then there exists a solution if and only if $$\gcd(n, p-1) \mid f.$$

You can prove this using primitive roots. Assuming that $p$ is a prime number, there exists a primitive root $a$. This means that
$$a^i \equiv 1 \mod p \iff p-1 \mid i,$$
or equivalently, the powers $a^0, a^1, \ldots, a^{p-2}$ are equivalent to some permutation of $1,2,3,\ldots,p-1$ modulo $p$. In particular 2 is a power of $a$ with exponent $f$ times something relatively prime to $e$.

Not sure if this is a nice criterion, since you would need to know the order. However if you have the prime factorization of $p-1$, that can be computed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Computing a primitive root solves all similar problems. Unfortunately it is not trivial. A bad omen is that the list of moduli n for which -1 is a power mod. n was a newbie on OEIS (https://oeis.org/A126949). This the same question with 2 replaced by the simpler value -1.